# Linke differenet css and script file for each layout in ReacJs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have two different Layout(AdminLayout and CustomersLayout).
and both of them have some link for css and script file and i linke them in  in index.html.
I Want load Admin css file when AdminLayout render on page and load CustomersLayout css file when it render on page.

index.html:

```
 <!-- css file for CustomersLayout -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/vendor/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/vendor/materialdesignicons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/vendor/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/vendor/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/vendor/nice-select.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/vendor/jquery.jqZoom.css">
    
    <!-- css file for AdminLayout -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
  </head>
```

CustomersLayout:

```
const LeyoutCustomers = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <HeaderCustomers/>
      {children}
      <FooterCustomers/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

AdminLayout:

```
const LeyoutAdmin = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <HeaderAdmin/>
      {children}
      <FooterAdmin/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Index.js]

If All css and script file for two layout load The design of the page is broken.

Comment: CSS is global, so you'll likely want to try to refactor your `classname` attributes to more accurately scope the CSS selectors/rules you are trying to use. [`React-Helmet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) might be able to help you with the issue of loading specific scripts in the document head though.